# Sudo giving error after installing homebrew and Laravel Valet

Tags: macos, homebrew, laravel-valet

I had just installed homebrew and afterwards I installed Laravel Valet. 
I am now not able to run any sudo commands at all, and it basically broke my computer.

This is the errors I get when running sudo in terminal

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/brew: Alias `BREW' already defined near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/valet: Alias `VALET' already defined near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/brew near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Any help appreciated

This is my sudoer for `/etc/sudoers.d/brew`:

```
Cmnd_Alias BREW = /usr/local/bin/brew *
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: BREW
```

And this is my sudoer for `/etc/sudoers.d/valet`:

```
Cmnd_Alias VALET = /usr/local/bin/valet *
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VALET
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems when trying to disable password requirement for group admin or users brew and valet. Try to change each sudoers.d file to something as :

```
Cmnd_Alias BREW = /usr/local/bin/brew *
brew ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or in a general way, as inside admin group

```
Cmnd_Alias BREW = /usr/local/bin/brew *
%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: BREW
```

Comment: How do I change the sudoers without sudo access? When I run sudo I just get the error

Comment: It didn't work when I changed the sudoers like you wrote.

Comment: Had you rebooted? With that sudoers.d file, brew or any user does not need to put sudo password. Could you put here error message that appears to you?

Comment: Yes I rebooted and the exact errors still came. 
I made some testing and by just deleting the sudoers.d files I was still able to use homebrew and valet without any problems.